# Cannot read property 'moment' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a problem with momentjs and I have no idea why. I wrote this code a couple of days ago and it worked fine then, but today I got this error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'moment' of undefined`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import moment from 'moment'
import Datetime from 'react-datetime'
import './react-datetime.css'

let parseDate = str => {
  if (moment(str).isValid()) {
    return moment(str).toISOString()
  } else {
    return moment(str).toISOString()
  }
}

export default class DateInput extends Component {
  render() {
    const yesterday = Datetime.moment().subtract(1, 'day') //Error occur on this line.
    const valid = current => {
      return current.isAfter(yesterday)
    }

    const Datetime = (
      <div>
        <Datetime
          isValidDate={valid}
          timeFormat="HHmm"
          dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
          onChange={e => {
            this.props.onChange(parseDate(e._d))
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
    if (this.props.value) {
      return { Datetime }
    } else {
      return <p>Inget datum angivet</p>
    }
  }
}
```

I bet the problem is really basic, but I have no idea why this is happening.

Thanks for reading and I hope we can solve it!

Comment: Why do you over-write the `Datetime` object?

Comment: What do you mean @Cristy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import Datetime from 'react-datetime'` makes `Datetime` available for use in the scope of your script. However you set it again inside `render`

```
const Datetime = (
  <div>
    <Datetime
      isValidDate={valid}
      timeFormat="HHmm"
      dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
      onChange={e => {
        this.props.onChange(parseDate(e._d))
      }}
    />
  </div>
)
```

In javascript, function's scope takes precedence over the global/script scope (where your function is declared). And since you used `Datetime` in a statement before the declaration you're referencing to an `undefined` variable/constant

> **P.S.** In ECMAScript 2015, let (const) will not hoist the variable to the top of the block. However, referencing the variable in the block before the variable declaration results in a ReferenceError. The variable is in a "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block until the declaration is processed.

Comment: I understand, did not know that! My friend suggested to separete the logic from the JSX (hehe)..

Answer (score 0):

Moment takes the argument inside itself, its a global function.
I suppose Datetime has no such function like 'moment'.
maybe

```
moment(Datetime)
```

?

```
const yesterday = moment(Datetime).subtract(1, 'day')
```

and i don't know what is Datetime in your code... take a look at [Moment.js: Parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: Hey. I followed the datepickers docs where they showed how to disable different types of dates: https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime . So I don't think `moment(Datetime)` is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Working with moment every day... you wont get moment function from moment.js library in some react object for time explanation...